# Is an Indian citizen allowed to travel from Saudi Arabia to India at this time?

Tags: indian-citizens, covid-19, saudi-arabia

I am an Indian citizen.

My father works in Saudi Arabia as a driver. I haven't seen my father for 7 years. I have heard in the news that Saudi Arabia has banned travel to red listed countries like India, due to COVID. Does this rule apply to foreign workers, including Indians?

Answer (score 2):

No, it only applies to Saudis, even Saudis can travel if they have a valid reason and apply through "Absher App".

However, currently going back to Saudi will be really hard for non-Saudis who are coming from the high risk areas, India is on top of the list.

Comment: Nean der thal thank you for your advice.it really helped me.